# Mute Button Missing?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, mute

I upgraded to a Samsung Galaxy S4 from an iPhone 4 today and have been setting various settings. When I first made a call there was a mute button in the middle bottom of the screen. Now, after I have changed settings, there is no more mute button.

I am at a lost as to what I changed to make my mute button disappear.

What do I do to see the mute button?

Note: I am referring to muting my phone during a call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

1.**Settings** > tap **Home Screen Mode** > select **standard mode**
2.Tap apply and reboot.